50s-60s movie about a country man who goes on an adventure
I have a very faint recollection of this movie, having watched it as a kid. The general plot was about a big man (who may or may not have been an English or Scottish lumberjack), who lived in a tiny cottage on top of a luscious green meadow with a little dog. He goes on a big adventure across the world and comes back a changed man (potentially returning with a wife?)
I remember the aesthetic of his little cottage being similar to The Sound of Music, so I'd guess it's a mid 50s to mid 60s movie. Anyone have any ideas what it could be? 

Could you describe some of the adventures he went on? What makes this movie stick out in your mind? Also what country did you see it in?

I saw it on British TV in the late 90s. I know the movie was definitely in English, and I'm leaning to thinking it was a British film. It was shown during the middle of the day so must have been family-friendly in terms of rating. In terms of the adventures, I feel the sea may have played a part but I'm not 100% sure.

Difficult to be certain from your description but it sounds like Geordie.
This is a gentle Launder & Gilliat film in black & white from 1955.  It is about a simple scottish forester who, through a suitably bizarre set of circumstances, is picked as a hammer thrower in the British team in the 1956 Melbourne Commonwealth Games.
It is a fish-out-of-water comedy as he travels by sea to Australia and finds love.

Wow, I think that is it! I looked up a clip on YouTube and it looks incredibly familiar and the story sounds right too. The colors and beautiful scenery also look how I remember. I'm gonna buy the DVD from amazon. Thanks! I'd been searching for that for about ten years.
